# difference between *p++ and ++*p

Tags: c, pointers, printf

```
int a = 5;
int *p = &a;
printf("%d\n\n", ++*p);
printf("%d\n", *p++);
```

`++*p` is equivalent to `++(*p)`. But `*p++` increments the pointer, not the value pointed by p.
But I am not able to understand why the printf statement in my code shows same value "6". 
Is there any specific logic behind this?

Comment: As for why `*p++` increments the pointer and not the value `p` points to, it's because the postfix `++` operator has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference operator `*`.

Comment: **(1):** Expression `++*p` evaluates as `*p = *p + 1`. This increments value of variable pointed by `p`. `p` points to `a` so value of `a` incremented to 6 and first `printf()` outputs: 6.  

**(2):** Whereas, in `*p++` because of postfix `++`,  `printf()` first prints value of `*p` that is 6 from previous expression then `p` increment to next location  of `a`.

Answer (score 6):

Sure. When you print `*p` for the second time, you have already incremented it (the value pointed to by the pointer) on the line with the first call to `printf()`.

```
int a = 5;                
int *p = &a;              // p = &a, *p = 5
printf("%d\n\n", ++*p);   // p = &a, *p = 6
printf("%d\n", *p++);     // p = &a + 1, *(p - 1) = a = 6 (still!)
```

Comment: The comment on the last line is a bit misleading. Once `p` is `&a + 1`, `*p` is obviously not 6 any more.

Comment: @sepp2k Fair enough, fixed.