# What's the difference between there two pointer statements

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Just wondering what the difference was between these two lines of code and exactly what they are doing:

```
p*++
++*p
```

Comment: Is any statement available in c or c++ like `p*++`...?

Comment: did you try searching google or existing stack overflow questions before posting this?

Comment: check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487644/difference-between-p-and-p

Answer (score 3):

- `*p` is value of the pointer pointing to.
- also `*` uses as multiplication operator (`int a = 5*6;`)
- `p++` is post increment the value of p
- `++p` is pre increment the value of p.

so

- `++*p` is pre increment the value of pointer point to.
- `p*++` gives you a compile error, because of no meaning